# Text formula to return characters between two "." characters

Tags: formula

I'm trying to create a formula field that returns a number. The source of the field is a text value such as the following examples.

- 0.**0**.004.0
- 1.**24**.004.0
- 3.**336**.004.0
- 4.**672**.002.0

The goal is to store the values in bold above in the formula number field. I believe this is possible with a couple text functions (Begins, Find, Left and Right) wrapped in a Value function to return the number represented by the text highlighted above.

Can you solve this?

Comment: Alot of hacking resulting in: VALUE(RIGHT(My_Field__c,(FIND(".", My_Field__c)+3)))... I think Alex's suggestion of using "MID" is the key here... thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should do the job.

It finds the position of the first `.` in the string. Then finds the position of the first `.` in the rest of the string and uses `MID` and a slight offset to pick out the value from between the two positions.

```
VALUE(
  MID(
    YourField__c, 
    FIND(".", YourField__c) + 1, 
    FIND(".", RIGHT(YourField__c, LEN(YourField__c) - FIND(".", YourField__c)))
  )
)
```

Comment: Alex, this works perfectly. I tried adding a bit of error handling to prevent "#Error!". This can occurr for example with two consecutive "." chars. I modified the formula as follows:

Comment: I modified the formula as follows: IF(ISNUMBER(TEXT(VALUE(
MID(
App_Recovery_Priority_Sequence_Value__c,
FIND(".", App_Recovery_Priority_Sequence_Value__c) + 1,
FIND(".", RIGHT(App_Recovery_Priority_Sequence_Value__c, LEN(App_Recovery_Priority_Sequence_Value__c) - FIND(".", App_Recovery_Priority_Sequence_Value__c)))
)
))), VALUE(
MID(
App_Recovery_Priority_Sequence_Value__c,
FIND(".", App_Recovery_Priority_Sequence_Value__c) + 1,
FIND(".", RIGHT(App_Recovery_Priority_Sequence_Value__c, LEN(App_Recovery_Priority_Sequence_Value__c) - FIND(".", App_Recovery_Priority_Sequence_Value__c)))
)
),672)

Comment: I should clarify, the error handling is not working as expected. It is not a big concern but error handling for the formula returning #error! would be a nice add-on.